# Ngrok not passing my post request on to localhost

Tags: asp.net-mvc, webhooks, ngrok, stripe.net

I'm trying to set up a webhook for Stripe and I've created a controller, according to the [Stripe doc](https://stripe.com/docs/webhooks#signatures) , to do it in ASP.Net MVC running in a virtual machine (maybe that changes things?). I've been testing the action in the controller to see if I can receive posts, so I'm using Postman to send my localhost posts requests which are working. But now I need to use Ngrok to give my localhost a url so that Stripe can use it. I'm running ngrok and passing in these parameters to run

```
ngrok http -host-header="localhost:44368" 44368
```

and here is what I see, everything looks ok

[image]

But now when I try and use it in Postaman

> ex https://11d1ba97.ngrok.io/StripeWebHook/Index

I get a 502 Bad Gateway message and the action method never gets hit.

I get the same problem when I try and send a test webhook from Stripe.
FYI - The request times from Ngrok using 'localhost:4040' show all my response times as 0ms.

[image]

**Update** - I was emailed by ngrok 
"The trouble is the HTTPS. ngrok terminates HTTPS traffic and then forwards the unencrypted http traffic through to your local application. You want to do one of two things:

1) make your application expose an HTTP port as well and forward traffic to that
2) use ngrok's TLS tunnels (which hand of TLS traffic to you for termination). with this option you have all the complexities of doing cert management, cert mismatches, etc, just fyi. i'd recommend #1 if possible"

Question - anyone know how to open up a http port in a ASP.Net MVC app using Https?

Comment: Did you find a solution for this?

Comment: Hi Morton. No, I gave up. It might have something to do with me running it through my VM on a Macbook. I'll revisit this next week when I get back to working on that part of the application and let you know. If you found a solution please reply.

Comment: I found out my problem was not exactly the same as yours. I got mine to work with `ngrok.exe http -region eu -host-header=rewrite mydomain:80` it is not related to your problem with https I think.

Answer (score 30):

My problem was that the breakpoint in my application wasn't getting hit.

I was using

```
ngrok http 58533
```

but changing it to the following allowed my breakpoint to get hit.

```
ngrok http -host-header=rewrite localhost:58533
```

Comment: `ngrok http -host-header=rewrite http://localhost:58533` It worked for me. Thank you.

Comment: 58533 is port with tls?

Comment: I needed to add to the flag as `--host-header=rewrite` to get it to work

Answer (score 12):

Bit late to the party :)
I could get http working by un-checking Enable SSL flag in Properties.

Step 1: Right click Web Api project, select Properties
[image]

Step 2: Download and install extension

https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=DavidProthero.NgrokExtensions

Step 3: Start ngrok Tunnel from Visual Studio

[image]

(image from https://raw.githubusercontent.com/dprothero/NgrokExtensions/master/docs/img/menu-item.png)

Step 4: Copy Forwarding http url

[image]

Step 5: Paste in Postman, and append the controller/action

[image]

you get 200! (upvotes? :))