# Ngrok access subdomain

Tags: api, ngrok

I would like to access a controller method with ngrok but it does not enter my breakpoint.

The controller method I would like to access is: http://localhost:44365/twilio/incoming

I first ran this command in ngrok: ngrok http 44339. This provided an ngrok url like 'http://[....].ngrok.io'.

Next, I hooked up this ngrok and when I called the base address + 'twilio/incoming' it shows this in my ngrok window (so I assume the request got into ngrok).

[image]

However, the problem is that the breakpoint is not getting hit.

Answer (score 0):

Solved in the meantime (with the help of [Ngrok not passing my post request on to localhost](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46947548/ngrok-not-passing-my-post-request-on-to-localhost)):

The problem arises when routing to https. In that case you can add: '-host-header=rewrite'

So final command looks like this:
ngrok http https://localhost:44365 -host-header=rewrite