# Webhook not hitting development webserver tunneled using ngrok

Tags: webhooks, ngrok, http-tunneling

I am working on a Django server that should verify a payment via a webhook post. When I spawn the server in development mode and tunneled using ngrok, I don't receive the incoming webhook. I have verified using [webhook.site](https://webhook.site) that the payment service did send the webhook, and therefore the problem seems to be my ngrok service not allowing the traffic through. My ngrok was started using

```
./ngrok http -region=eu 8000



ngrok by @inconshreveable                                                                                               (Ctrl+C to quit)
                                                                                                                                        
Session Status                online                                                                                                    
Account                       JianDk (Plan: Free)                                                                                       
Version                       2.3.40                                                                                                    
Region                        Europe (eu)                                                                                               
Web Interface                 http://127.0.0.1:4040                                                                                     
Forwarding                    http://20e8-94-147-65-45.eu.ngrok.io -> http://localhost:8000                                             
Forwarding                    https://20e8-94-147-65-45.eu.ngrok.io -> http://localhost:8000                                            
                                                                                                                                        
Connections                   ttl     opn     rt1     rt5     p50     p90                                                               
                              12      0       0.00    0.01    1.26    233.97
```

When I google similar problems with the webhook traffic over ngrok, it seems from this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46947548/ngrok-not-passing-my-post-request-on-to-localhost) that ngrok does not allow traffic through https.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of ngrok, I used [localtunnel](https://theboroer.github.io/localtunnel-www/). This solved the problem.